# How can I make to make a complex query for my login system?

Tags: python, sql, database, authentication, tkinter

##### I want a login system which relates to a register database I made

I am trying to make a complex query which takes the user input:

```
    Entry(self.root,
          textvariable=self.username)  ##There is more but I want this to be as minimal as possible 
          
    Entry(self.root,
          textvariable=self.password,
          show="*")
```

This user input then gets compared with the one in the database.
**This is where I am finding it diffucult**:

```
def login(self):
    con = sqlite3.connect("register.db")  ##The database which I want to open and compare user inputs to 
    c = con.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM register")
    slist = c.fetchall()
    values = [row[0] for row in slist]
    values2 = [row[1] for row in slist]
    if self.username.get() == values and self.password.get()==values2:
        command=self.invcon  ##A external thing I want to open if the user enters the data in correctly
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Error","Error"parent=self.root)
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

The error which is now happening is instead of opening the new window it moves into the else and pops up with the error box.
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NI1rd.png)

Comment: You either specify the columns you want, like `select username from register`, or you do `select * from register` to get _all_ columns.

Comment: @jarlh I have changed that so now it calls to both columns in the table. However, It seems to pass the if and goes to the else opening the error box.

Comment: `values` and `values2` are *list*, so the comparison between a string and a list will always be `False`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL `"SELECT username * FROM register"` should be `"SELECT * FROM register"`.

Also `values` and `values2` are *list*, so the comparison between a string (`self.username.get()` or `self.password.get()`) and a list will always be `False`.

However, you don't need to select all records from the table, just select the record with the username and password is enough:

```py
def login(self):
    con = sqlite3.connect("register.db")  ##The database which I want to open and compare user inputs to 
    c = con.cursor()
    # assume the fields required are 'username' and 'password'
    # change them to suit your table definition
    c.execute("SELECT 1 FROM register WHERE username = ? AND password = ?", (self.username.get(), self.password.get()))
    result = c.fetchone() # get the record if any
    if result:
        # record found
        command=self.invcon  ##A external thing I want to open if the user enters the data in correctly
    else:
        # record not found
        messagebox.showerror("Error", parent=self.root)
    con.close()
```

Comment: Thanks your feedback has helped. The error I am now facing is a attribute error saying command=self.invcon has no attribute to the class

Comment: @needhelpfr2 It is just copied from your posted code.  If it is not a valid statement, you need to think what is the correct statement.

Comment: yeah I'm sorry my def invcon wasn't indented properly. However now nothing happens when I press the login button.

Comment: @needhelpfr2 My answer is how to solve your original question.  Now you raise another question after fixing the original one.  It is better to ask a new question on that instead of keep changing your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand all of the errors but when selecting something from a table (in this case 'register') you can either select things by listing them up like:

```
c.execute("SELECT username, password ... FROM register")
```

or you simply select everything:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM register")
```

In this case you did both ("SELECT username * FROM ...") which is why there could be an error.

Comment: Thanks your code helped me select from all the columns. However, it opens the error message instead of the new window. Thanks for your help thus far.